# What are the drawbacks of using linux on a usb flash with persistence?

Tags: linux, liveusb, persistence

I've been interested in installing a linux distro on a 64gb flash and using it as a portable os. I've heard many of the pros, such as the obvious portability, but haven't really heard about the cons. What are they?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While most computers nowadays have USB3, you will really notice a speed differenc if you're limited to USB2 speeds. Boot and load times are primarily the affected areas, so if you can live with that, this won't really be an issue.

There is also the generally increased wear and tear that comes with a portable device, so take the posibility of data theft and loss into consideration when making your choice.

Outside of that, I would have a hard time living with only 64Gb nowadays (although I used to make due with 43Mb on my first PC), but scaling it up to a bigger drive when available shouldn't be a problem.

In short: The downsides aren't that big, especially if you're going to use it as a secondary OS, or just to try it out. I'm sure you already know this, but many linux distros are made to be compact and run this way, so if the limitations don't bother you, then I'm sure you'll like it.

Comment: Enlarging on @Jamund's good answer: even the current fastest flash drive I've used, UHS 3, seems slower than running from HDD, but it is not unreasonably slow. Also, as he states, there is "wear and tear": flash RAM has a large but finite number of cycles before failure, so it might fail sooner from heavy disk use.

Comment: An external USB 3.0 SSD might help with the size and speed issues as well as be more durable than a cheap USB stick.